# How to resolve multiple inheritance ambiguities in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, methods, ambiguous

I have a small program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class X{
    public:
        bool something(){
            return true;
        }
};

class A: public X<A>{
};


class B: public A, public X<B>{
};


template <typename T>
bool use(T &t)
{
    return t.something();
}



int main()
{
    B b;
    std::cout << "use returned: " << use(b);
}
```

This will not compile because there is an ambiguity as to which of the two possible versions of `something()` should be selected:

> ```
> In instantiation of 'bool use(T&) [with T = B]':
> 30:43:   required from here
> 22:20: error: request for member 'something' is ambiguous
> 6:14: note: candidates are: bool X<T>::something() [with T = B]
> 6:14: note:                 bool X<T>::something() [with T = A]
>  In function 'bool use(T&) [with T = B]':
> 23:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
> ```

My question is, how can I resolve this ambiguity if the only place I can edit is the body of `use()`?

Comment: You could cast it to a X<T> or an A object. For example `((A)t).something()`

Comment: I am a little unsure how that cast would look like. Just good old (mytype)?

Comment: Yes `((sometype)t).something()` make sure you have the right `()` for order of operators.

Comment: Also let me know if this does not work (I tested it and it did) I have some other suggestions you could try.

Comment: Which version of something do you want called?

Comment: @bpeikes In this case the most specialized one (X<B>)

Comment: You can use different namespace per class or use [vitaut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47735665/5238753) answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For example, you can qualify the call to `something` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/iXPdeh)):

```
template <typename T>
bool use(T &t)
{
    return t.A::something();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a specialization of the template “use” for the case where T derives from X and then casts to X inside.

```
template <typename T>
class X{
    public:
        bool something(){
            return true;
        }
};

class A: public X<A>{
};


class B: public A, public X<B>{
};

#
# If class derives from X<T> make sure to cast to X<T> before calling something
#
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<X<T>, T>::value, bool>::type use(T &t)
{
     return static_cast<X<T>&>(t).something();
}

#
# This gets run for everything that doesn't derive from X<T>
#
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<X<T>, T>::value, bool>::type use(T &t)
{
     return t.something();
}
```

Have to check the syntax though, but this should make sure you get it for your special case while allowing anything with only one “something” call.

Comment: Updated code above to compile. Note that this allows you add specializations for any case where T is derived from multiple classes that have a "something" method. You would just add another template that specializes and casts.